# What material is my residence-adjoining common wall made from?

Tags: walls

My house is a twin built in 1920. Most of the walls are plaster, some are drywall. Knocking on these with my knuckle yields a hollow sound, like tapping a door or window. However the center wall that divides our house is extremely hard, and when I tap on it, there is no sound whatsoever; except for some guitar sounds (mostly low strings) I can't hear a single thing going on next door.

What is this material? It runs down the middle of our entire house. To my eyes it's just a painted white wall!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplex/twin - probably a firewall, or "party wall" in the "old-shool, solid masonry" sense. Depending on the locale, sometimes a LOT of solid masonry (like 2 feet/600mm.)

Comment: Yes, brick, block, or stone set in mortar. Could be poured concrete, but that's less likely.

Comment: "Party wall" - oh boy. It is somewhere in the range of 2 feet thick we think, so that makes sense. This house continues to impressively be rock solid. I guess almost literally. It's amazing how little I can hear.